# MacBook shuts down with 60% battery

Tags: macbook-pro, macos

My laptop shuts off with 50%-60% battery levels without saying anything - just dims the screen go off. If I try to turn it on again, it shows me the big "low battery level" indication and won't start unless i plug it in. Is it normal?

MacBook Pro (Retina, 15-inch, Early 2013)

macOS Sierra 10.12.3

Comment: Try running the Apple Diagnostics Test to check for hardware issues.

Answer (score 3):

This is not normal, shutdown the laptop and the press the **Power Button** and hold down **Command + Alt/Option + P + R**. Hold these buttons for around 20 seconds. This might fix the issue.

I had the same issue on a MacBookPro10,1 (15" Retina, Mid 2012) and reseting the NVRAM fixed it for me.

If that does not fix it, it might be a worth a trip to the Apple Store.

Comment: will give it a try! why does reseting NVRAM help?

Comment: I'm not exactly sure, I was told to do this by an Apple Technician when trying to solve another issue. Resetting the NVRAM fixed this issue for my and my other issue (kernel panics, not related to battery).